# Unhandled JS Exception: TyperError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.onPress.bind')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm trying to make a button in React Native using TouchableOpacity's onPress. I got it working before, but now that I added some extra functionality in the function 'like', it does not work anymore.

The onPress should give an argument with the function.

I get the Error `Unhandled JS Exception: TyperError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.onPress.bind')` in my iOS simulator.

My code:

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = { liked: [false, false, false] }
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this)
  }

  like = (id) => {
    const liked = this.state.liked
    liked[id] = !liked[id]
    this.setState({
      liked: [!this.state.liked[0], false, false ],
    });
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper style={SliderStyles.wrapper} showsButtons={false}>
        <View style={SliderStyles.slide1}>
          <View style={CardStyles.card}>
            <View style={CardStyles.card_img} >
              <Image source={require('./recources/ny.jpg')} style={CardStyles.images}/>
            </View>
            <View style={CardStyles.card_details}>
              <Text style={TextStyles.card_title} >New York</Text>
              <View style={CardStyles.card_action}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={CardStyles.card_button} onPress={() => this.like(0)}>
                  
                  <Image source={ this.state.liked[0] === true ? 
                                  require('./recources/icons/heart_closed.png') : 
                                  require('./recources/icons/heart_open.png')
                                } style={CardStyles.card_button_img}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <Text style={TextStyles.card_name}>Seppe De Langhe</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      </Swiper>
    );
  }
}
```

[Picture of what my iOS simulator looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoOpk.png)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your error is caused because `this.onPress` is not a function of the `<App>` component. `.bind` is only used on functions that are being passed into parameters to ensure their scope when they are being passed through components not the parameters themselves. just remove the bind and it should work.

Comment: You don't need to bind `onPress` like that. It's not a class method, and you're using class fields so it's unnecessary. Simply remove that line in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't have an `onPress` method to bind, your method is called `like` and because you're using an arrow function it's already bound.

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    liked: [false, false, false],
  };

  like = (id) => {
    this.setState(state => {
      state.liked[id] = !state.liked[id];
      return state;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper style={SliderStyles.wrapper} showsButtons={false}>
        <View style={SliderStyles.slide1}>
          <View style={CardStyles.card}>
            <View style={CardStyles.card_img} >
              <Image source={require('./recources/ny.jpg')} style={CardStyles.images}/>
            </View>
            <View style={CardStyles.card_details}>
              <Text style={TextStyles.card_title} >New York</Text>
              <View style={CardStyles.card_action}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={CardStyles.card_button} onPress={() => this.like(0)}>
                  
                  <Image source={ this.state.liked[0] === true ? 
                                  require('./recources/icons/heart_closed.png') : 
                                  require('./recources/icons/heart_open.png')
                                } style={CardStyles.card_button_img}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <Text style={TextStyles.card_name}>Seppe De Langhe</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      </Swiper>
    );
  }
}
```